# Sharing routines within a user community

Tags: postgresql, julia

Im building a toolbox for a certain branch of biology. One of the reasons Julia was chosen is its simplicity, as biologists wont be assumed to be able to write complex C-code
What I'd like to add is a way for users to share their own custom methods for others to review/verify/use, both to promote collaboration and to add a bit of sense of community

What Im sure of is that this specific demography of (mostly) biologist wont be able or have patience to fork a github project or anything that could be considered remotely complex, especially when it wont benefit them explicitly to do so

So, what I'd like to do is provide the simplest of interfaces, with the add/view options to either add a routine or view routines (along with descriptions, ratings etc)

I can only think of two ways to accomplish storing the scripts pushed by users, by having them on a server, or, more simply, using SQL

**tl;dr** can postgresql store scripts or is that a terrible idea

I ask, mainly because there will be 'raw data' available on a postgresql server, and I'd like to be able to keep that and the 'community methods' both in the same place for convenience sake

Comment: PostgreSQL can store scripts easily, but you should think of a user interface first. Look for a GUI for the source versioning system of your choice.

Comment: _Sharing code is a complicated problem, it is going to need a complicated solution_. This is a kinda no free lunch rule. You are going to end up replicating a lot of the functionality of version control, plus the functionality of a blog/CMS/stack-overflow like site (for commenting and rating).
Most Blogs/CMS/stack-overflow sites, and also many version control systems (eg TFS) are backed by a database. 
But implementing your own is probably not a path you want to go down -- unless you have a lot of time and experience, and know a lot more about UX than any maker of version control software.

Comment: I think github is the best way to do this. If you give everybody full access to one repo, they won't have to deal with forking and things are easier. You can also use a GUI git client to help avoid the command line. When they see version histories with changes highlighted and inline comments/discussion I think they'll immediately see how it benefits them. Moreover, github is a transferable skill and there is plenty of help available online.

Comment: Somehow, it never even crossed my mind making the 'github-version' in a GUI, as the entire application is intended to be run inside the REPL, but seeing as Im already creating a GUI for the setup + settings I might aswell add this feature in aswell. Thanks for your replies

Comment: I personally agree that github GUI is probably the best idea, especially for julia, but I do know that version control can overwhelm newcomers. Were you thinking of something like MATLAB's file-exchange?

Comment: exactly, but I dont have time to make a complex webpage, so Im sure that a GUI is the best option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments to this question:

Version control is an excellent solution to sharing control, but from a scientist's perspective, it can be difficult and complicated. Luckily, [GitHub](https://github.com) now offers a GUI that is easy to learn and yet retains a lot of the power of Git. For instance, GitHub allows one to edit files directly from the web UI.